# How do i extract a string line to output email and message

Tags: php, string, email, output

i have a string like:

```
  $str = 'xyz@email.com[24ab@gmail.com has mail me]abc@email.Com[i want to...] and others...';
```

in my achievement i want to be able to use the text inside the box as an email message to email behind the box like:

```
  $to = 'xyz@email.com';
  $msg = '24ab@gmail.com has mail me';
  $to = 'abc@email.com';
  $msg = 'i want to...';
```

i dont really no how to run on php i just want to do some thing   am sorry

```
  foreach($str as $both)
  {
  $to = $both["to"];
  $msg = $both["msg"];

   $to = $email;
   $subject = 'the subject';
   $message = '$msg';
   $headers = 'stringemail@gm.Com';
   $go = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   if($go)
   {
   echo 'good result';
   }
   }
```

great thanks for your impact in my soluction

Comment: How are you forming that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` it:

```
$str = 'xyz@email.com[24ab@gmail.com has mail me]abc@email.Com[i want to...]'; 
$str = explode( "]", $str );

foreach ( $str as $value ) {
    $temp = explode( "[", $value );
    if ( count( $temp ) == 2 ) {
        echo "<br /> Email: " . $temp[0];      /* $temp[0] - is the email */
        echo "<br /> Msg: " . $temp[1];        /* $temp[1] - is the message */
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

This will result to:

```
Email: xyz@email.com
Msg: 24ab@gmail.com has mail me

Email: abc@email.Com
Msg: i want to...
```

Comment: can it go for mail as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, check here https://regex101.com/r/7khpKv/1

```
$regExpresion = '/(.*?)\[(.*?)\]/';
$str          = 'xyz@email.com[24ab@gmail.com has mail me]abc@email.Com[i want to...]434343@wewe.com[other mesage]';

preg_match_all($regExpresion, $str, $aMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);


foreach ($aMatches as $aMail)
{
    $to      = $aMail[1];
    $message = $aMail[2];
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $headers = 'From: stringemail@gm.Com';

    $go = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($go)
    {
        echo 'good result';
    }
}
```